# Deploying nodejs app on a web server

Tags: node.js, deployment

I know absolutely nothing about nodejs. I have been asked to deploy a nodejs app on a web server.
http://grab.by/vl2w  shows my file structure. Can someone please help me to deploy this on any web server.

Comment: are you sure that's a nodejs app? i don't see `package.json` anywhere

Answer (score -1):

Node cannot be deployed to a web server. Node apps are used to implement the server it self. You don't serve them like a web page that runs JavaScript on the client. On node the JavaScript runs on the node server.